# apexcharts add click event to label

Tags: javascript, events, label, apexcharts

I have an  line-bar-area apexchart.
That looks like this:
[image]

I succeeded to add an onclick event to the datapoints.
But I would like to add an onclick event to the labels (like 01, 02, 03, 04, 05)
Does anyone knows how to do that?
The code I use for the datapoints is this:

```
var options = {
  chart: {
    height: 400,
    type: 'line',
    stacked: false,
    events: {
      dataPointSelection: (event, chartContext, config) => { 
      var selecteddate = pad(config.dataPointIndex + 1, 2);
      console.log(selecteddate);    
     }
   }
 }
```

This works but how can I add events to the labels?
Or is this not possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to do it by adding an event listener to my page.
It may be not the label, but the tooltip is also great.

```
$(".apexcharts-xaxistooltip").click(function(){
    var selecteddate = $(this).text();
    // do something
});
```

After that I also overwrite the css of the tooltip.

```
.tooltip-inner {
  background-color: #00acd6 !important;
  /*!important is not necessary if you place custom.css at the end of your css calls. For the purpose of this demo, it seems to be required in SO snippet*/
  color: #fff;
}
.apexcharts-xaxistooltip{
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: all;
}
.apexcharts-xaxistooltip:hover{
  background: #46A7B3;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

This gives me the nice hover effect and clickable cursor.
In this way the tooltips are clickable and won't fade out when out of hover.
[image]

Comment: In My case this is only work once

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same problem for a while, if anyone is experiencing a case scenario where onClick is needed on the labels here's how I solved it:

```
componentDidMount () {
    //get the DOM elements of the labels , classes may vary so check in dev tools.
    const labels = document.querySelectorAll('.apexcharts-text.apexcharts-yaxis-label')

    // you'll get NodeList so iterate & add click event listeners 
        labels.forEach(item => {
          item.addEventListener('click', event => {
            // do whatever onClick
            console.log(event.target)
          })
        })
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

In My case. I did the following
I changed the CSS property and then I added the click event

```js
const labels = document.querySelectorAll('.apexcharts-xaxis-label');
            labels.forEach(item => {
                item.addEventListener('click', event => {
                    const target = event.target as HTMLTextAreaElement;}
                    });
                });
            });
```

```css
::ng-deep.apexcharts-xaxis-label{
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: all;
}

::ng-deep.apexcharts-xaxis-label:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I could see there is a click event 'xAxisLabelClick' on ApexChart label
I didn't get a chance to try it
please see the documentation
https://apexcharts.com/docs/options/chart/events/

```js
 chart: {
    events: {
      xAxisLabelClick: function(event, chartContext, config) {
        // ...
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Today (6 may 2022), there is a specific event for this, e.g.

```
legendClick: function(chartContext, seriesIndex, config) {
               // get the id of the chart-element to get the specific chart (I have multiple charts on a page)
               console.log('chartConfigId', chartContext.el.id.split("-")[2]);
               console.log('seriesIndex', seriesIndex);
            }
```